# Android kernel bug: scheduling while atomic

Tags: android, linux, kernel, atomic

Im developing a custom kernel for android, but all of a sudden with a fresh build this error started appearing when the device goes to sleep and I try to wake it up:

```
[  131.925262] 
[  132.133514] mipi_dsi_panel mipi_dsi_panel.0: panel_display_on: DISPLAY_ON sent
[  132.296691] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  132.305450] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  132.311828] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 0 
[  132.311859] 
[  132.871978] BUG: scheduling while atomic: system_server/698/0x00000002
[  132.877929] Modules linked in: wlan(C)
[  132.881439] [<c010c0a8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x118) from [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710)
[  132.881469] [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710) from [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310)
[  132.881530] [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310) from [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c)
[  132.881561] [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c) from [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c)
[  132.881622] [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c) from [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc)
[  132.881652] [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc) from [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44)
[  132.881713] [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44) from [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564)
[  132.881744] [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564) from [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70)
[  132.881774] [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70) from [<c0105d60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[  132.958679] pm8xxx-pwrkey pm8xxx-pwrkey: unexpected key release
[  132.972351] pm8xxx-pwrkey pm8xxx-pwrkey: unexpected key press
[  133.065612] pm8xxx-pwrkey pm8xxx-pwrkey: key status changed to 1
[  133.159057] BUG: scheduling while atomic: system_server/698/0x00000002
[  133.164642] Modules linked in: wlan(C)
[  133.168426] [<c010c0a8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x118) from [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710)
[  133.177429] [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710) from [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310)
[  133.186004] [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310) from [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c)
[  133.195251] [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c) from [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c)
[  133.204101] [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c) from [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc)
[  133.212524] [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc) from [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44)
[  133.220672] [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44) from [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564)
[  133.229064] [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564) from [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70)
[  133.237426] [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70) from [<c0105d60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[  133.401031] clearpad clearpad: synaptics_clearpad_set_power: state=running
[  133.401031] clearpad clearpad: power OFF
[  133.565643] mipi_dsi_panel mipi_dsi_panel.0: panel_off: DISPLAY_OFF sent
[  133.818176] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  133.828186] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  133.842346] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 1 
[  133.842346] 
[  134.067871] BUG: scheduling while atomic: system_server/698/0x00000002
[  134.073547] Modules linked in: wlan(C)
[  134.077209] [<c010c0a8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x118) from [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710)
[  134.085998] [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710) from [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310)
[  134.094726] [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310) from [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c)
[  134.104064] [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c) from [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c)
[  134.112731] [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c) from [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc)
[  134.121215] [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc) from [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44)
[  134.129486] [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44) from [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564)
[  134.137817] [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564) from [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70)
[  134.146301] [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70) from [<c0105d60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[  134.269287] clearpad clearpad: synaptics_clearpad_set_power: state=running
[  134.269287] clearpad clearpad: power ON
[  134.328796] mdp4_overlay_mdp_perf_upd mdp clk is changed [1] from 0 to 177780000
[  134.375457] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  134.384490] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  134.390533] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 0 
[  134.390533] 
[  134.604705] mipi_dsi_panel mipi_dsi_panel.0: panel_display_on: DISPLAY_ON sent
[  135.050567] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  135.059295] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  135.065734] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 1 
[  135.065734] 
[  135.487274] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  135.497192] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  135.502929] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 0 
[  135.502929] 
[  138.195495] clearpad clearpad: synaptics_clearpad_set_power: state=running
[  138.195526] clearpad clearpad: power OFF
[  138.356140] mipi_dsi_panel mipi_dsi_panel.0: panel_off: DISPLAY_OFF sent
[  139.018493] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_QosPmcDeviceStateUpdateInd: 7219: nothing to process in PMC state 6
[  139.030792] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 1, hRSSI -79, Alpha 5
[  139.038757] wlan: [1053:E :HDD] hdd_conf_arp_offload: 903:  fenable = 1 
[  139.038757] 
[  152.279357] set_usb_max_current: setting current max to 1500
[  162.295837] set_usb_max_current: setting current max to 1500
[  172.312225] set_usb_max_current: setting current max to 1500
[  191.705749] wlan: [989:E :PE ] limHandleHeartBeatFailureTimeout: 7219: Probe_hb_failure: SME 12, MLME 16, HB-Count 0
[  191.716247] wlan: [989:E :PE ] limHandleHeartBeatFailureTimeout: 7226: Probe_hb_failure: for session:0 
[  191.726043] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 0, hRSSI -78, Alpha 5
[  191.731750] wlan: [989:E :TL ]  ----> CRegion 0, hRSSI -78, Alpha 5
[  191.746032] wlan: disconnected
[  191.748168] wlan(0) 00:00:00:00:00:00 Standalone
[  191.756958] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  191.763092] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  191.774414] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  191.787750] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.794677] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.815124] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.825012] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.832031] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.845947] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
[  202.330871] set_usb_max_current: setting current max to 1500
[  204.137451] wlan: [989:F :CTL] [PNO WDI] PREF_NETWORK_FOUND_IND Type (9) data (SSID=TP-LINK-24, RSSI=82)
[  204.146850] wlan: [989:E :SME] sme_PreferredNetworkFoundInd: 6168:  not enough data length 48 needed 48
[  211.043792] BUG: scheduling while atomic: system_server/698/0x00000002
[  211.050140] Modules linked in: wlan(C)
[  211.053680] [<c010c0a8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x118) from [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710)
[  211.062622] [<c090c990>] (__schedule+0x74/0x710) from [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310)
[  211.071289] [<c090b248>] (schedule_timeout+0x28/0x310) from [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c)
[  211.080596] [<c090c76c>] (wait_for_common+0x114/0x15c) from [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c)
[  211.089019] [<c0198e44>] (wait_rcu_gp+0x38/0x4c) from [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc)
[  211.097747] [<c05b9f40>] (evdev_ioctl+0x3f8/0x8bc) from [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44)
[  211.105987] [<c024c8dc>] (vfs_ioctl+0x20/0x44) from [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564)
[  211.114257] [<c024d2e4>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x474/0x564) from [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70)
[  211.122344] [<c024d420>] (sys_ioctl+0x4c/0x70) from [<c0105d60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
```

I have no idea how to debug this issue, could someone help me out with this?